# JavaScript getElementById Only Targeting One Page

Tags: javascript, dom-events

Here is a link to my website where you can access the code via Firebug rather than paste it all here. [www.chrismazzochi.com](http://www.chrismazzochi.com)

I don't understand why I am able to affect my h1 heading "Chris Mazzochi Web Designs" with id "brand" on my 'contact' page, but *not* on 3 other pages with the same h1 with the same id.  Those pages that are unaffected are the 'home', 'about', and 'portfolio' pages. I have heard folks recommend using `getElementByClassName`, but `getElementById` is working for all the other elements I have targeted.

In sum, only one element id of one page is being targeted by `getElementById` and the same element with the same id on the other three pages is not being affected.  Why?

Please help JavaScript wizards.  I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Look at this file **scripts1.js** line 41. This is the error you get `Cannot set property 'onmouseover' of null ` and that's why it does not work.

Answer (score 1):

This entire section here of the javascript code is "switching" between colours.

```
var myAside = document.getElementById ("brand");
myAside.onmouseout = function () {  
document.getElementById("brand").style.color = "blue";
//alert ("You're awesome!");}
```

It can be easily achieved with

```
#wrapper nav a:hover {
    color: blue;}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem isn't that you can't use `document.getElementById('brand')` effectively, the problem is that while you wrote code that does that, that code is never executed.

Before it gets to the `document.getElementById('fieldset')` which returns null. Then we use the result of it to execute a function on, which causes an error because you can't doa  function on null.

As this error is caused, the rest of the script is skipped and the bit with brand as id never happens...

Since you mentioned using Firebug already, I'll assume that you were aware of the error, so we'll let the answer be "the error causes the rest of the script not to be executed". One may also notice that this isn't always what happens. When an error occurs in an event, then only the rest of that event doesn't get executed, while when an error happens during normal execution of your script, the rest of the entire script is skipped.